# Looking for a decent time-tracking application for Mac

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, time-tracking

I am a freelance graphic designer and need to track the time spent on projects so I can bill my clients accordingly. There are a *ton* of services and applications out there but somehow none of them really fits.

Here's what I am looking for:

- A stable desktop app. I don't want to do my time tracking in the browser.
- Stop recording when screensaver or sleep mode starts.
- A product I can buy, not a subscription service. I feel more comfortable and in control if I pay $100 upfront than pay $10 a month
- An easy-to-use UI that tracks time by client, project and task.
- Billing support is a bonus, but not necessary.

Here is what I don't need, so if the solution contains it, at least is shouldn't interfere with a simple workflow and efficiency:

- Not necessary: Smartphone app, team collaboration, cloud.

All I want is a pay-once, stand-alone, well-supported and nicely designed time-tracking app. Do products exist in this space for OSX?